# REST API post request authenticate with API Key

Tags: rest, api, post

I'm building out a RESTful API. I'm using API keys for my GET requests (base64 encoded over https to be secure) however I'm confused how to "authenticate" with POST requests.

I've read about basic authentication but that uses a username and password.

Is it good practice/correct to authenticate a POST request with an API key also? Is that something you would include as part of the headers?

How do I process the authentication on the server side (endpoint)?

Here's an example of the endpoint that I have for logging in (POST request):

```
if ($_POST) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = strip_tags($password);

    // Regular Login

    $user = system::shared()->customers->login(
        $email,
        $password,
        $error
    );

    if ($user) {

        $output = json_encode($user);

    } else {

        $output = "Incorrect email/password. Please try again.";

    }

    echo $output;

} else {
    http_response_code(405);
}
```

How would I use the code above to "authenticate" an API key. Is that just a POST field?

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: You can put the authen_code in part of the header

Comment: Just curious, why can you not authenticate the same way you are authenticating GET requests?